# How to save ByteArray to HardDrive from Flash swf?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, mxml, arrays

How to save ByteArray to HardDrive from Flash swf?

So... I have a generated if flash ByteArray Now I want to save it to Hard Drive. How to du such thing?

Comment: If you mean saving it locally, you could use AIR it's FileStream class(http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#open%28%29).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it unless you are using a wrapper such as ZINC.

Answer (score 2):

If you're targeting Flash player 10, you can use FileReference.save() to do this from a swf